How to remove classes from a dependency using maven shade plugin both during compilation and build?
I am trying to remove a few classes from a dependency. I have tried using the following configuration in the pom.xml file but it is not working. The classes are still present in the fat jar. Can anyone help me with this?
I thought maybe they are present during the compile time, so I tried package but they are still present.
My intention is to remove the Event and BaseEvent classes from the models dependency.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.18</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.mua.dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>learn</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
    <name>Learn</name>
    <description>Learning Maven</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mua.dev</groupId>
            <artifactId>models</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-XDcompilePolicy=simple</arg>
                        <arg>-Xplugin:ErrorProne -XepOpt:NullAway:AnnotatedPackages=org.mua</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
                            <version>2.23.0</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.uber.nullaway</groupId>
                            <artifactId>nullaway</artifactId>
                            <version>0.10.15</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.26</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>org.mua.dev:models</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>org/mua/dev/models/Event.class</exclude>
                                        <exclude>org/mua/dev/models/BaseEvent.class</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>util</id>
            <url>https://nexus.mua.test.mydomain.bd/repository/mua/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>

It will even work for me if we can specifically include only the classes I want to include. Let's say I want to keep all dto in the below structure and remove all entity classes, and specifically EventEntity class.
models
 - dto
   - EventDto
   - SomeOtherDto
   - AnotherDto
   - YetAnotherDto
 - entity
   - EventEntity
   - SomeOtherEntity
   - AnotherEntity
   - YetAnotherEntity

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Why do you want to remove these classes?

We are registering repos based on these entities. So I want to exclude a few. And as maven supports this, i want to do it with maven @JFabianMeier

The configuration you provided looks correct, but here are a few things to double-check:

Make sure the class paths are correct in the <exclude> or
<include> sections of the Maven Shade Plugin configuration.

Ensure that the maven-shade-plugin is
executing after everything else in the build lifecycle (specifically
during the package phase).

Try cleaning and rebuilding the project to
remove any old artifacts that might still include the classes:
mvn clean package

Use the following command to inspect the
jar and ensure only the expected classes are included:
jar -tf <your-jar-file>


